# Issue with GROUP-BY using alias SELECT

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, interbase

I am using InterBase and struggle to put my query together.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT a.employee_no, ea.comment, ea.status as EmpadStatus, a.advices_value
FROM advices a
JOIN EMPAD EA ON (A.CODE = EA.CODE and ea.employee_no = A.employee_no ) AND EA.SUPER_FUND_CODE NOT IN ('000038','000113', '', ' ')
JOIN ALLDED ad ON AD.CODE = EA.CODE
WHERE a.employee_no = 13844 and a.advices_date between '1.10.2014' and '31.10.2014'
```

My result is this:

```
Employee_No   Comment   EmpadStatus   Advices_value
1             aaa       0             10.20
1                       1             30.50
1             bbb       0             69.30
```

What I need to do is to display `Employee_no`, `Comment` and `SUM` of `Advices_Value`, but `Comment` has to be ***first*** comment where `empad.status = 0`.

I was trying to use alias but I know that you cant group by it, so this query is not going to work

```
    SELECT a.employee_no, SUM(a.advices_value), (SELECT DISTINCT ea.comment
                                                 FROM EMPAD ea
                                                 JOIN allded ad on ea.code = ad.code
                                                 WHERE ea.employee_no = a.employee_no and ea.status = 0 and ad.super_type = 1) as comment
FROM advices a
JOIN EMPAD EA ON (A.CODE = EA.CODE and ea.employee_no = A.employee_no ) AND EA.SUPER_FUND_CODE NOT IN ('000038','000113', '', ' ')
JOIN ALLDED ad ON AD.CODE = EA.CODE
WHERE a.employee_no = 13844 and a.advices_date between '1.10.2014' and '31.10.2014'
GROUP BY a.employee_no, comment
```

So I need result like this :

```
Employee_no    Comment  Total
1              aaa      110.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally work with MySQL here, but I believe what I am going to say also a apply for InterBase.

You could just use a case or a if, if any of those exists in your databaseT, you could use a MIN, MAX or any other group function.

```
MIN(IF(EA.status = 0, a.comment, NULL))
```

or

```
MIN(CASE EA.status WHEN 0 then a.comment ELSE NULL END)
```

This works because group functions ignore NULL values.

The only thing is that, if there is more then one row with status = 0, you won't really be able to control and get the first or the last (you really can't control the order in which the rows are processed by group function unless the function itself support ORDER BY), unless your database has a group function that does the trick.

Comment: But just to be sure you understood, it won't really be the first comment found but the first alphabetically.

Comment: Yes, I did understand that and I wanted that way anyway. Thank you